# What is the equivalent of this Arabic expression?

Tags: expressions, politeness, foreign-phrases

In Arabic, when someone tells you "You look good today," or "Thank you for the flowers, they are beautiful," the polite answer is:

**It is not the flowers. Your eyes are so beautiful everything appears beautiful through them.**

What would be the best way to convey the same sentiment in English ?

Comment: You know, the best way to convey the same sentiment in English would be exactly your translation. It's a lovely sentiment, and it suffers not in translation.

Answer (score 3):

In terms of politeness, so far as I know, the best response to a compliment in English is a simple and sincere "thank you". All the etiquette guides agree:

> Say “Thank you,” in a friendly, calm and appreciative tone. Don’t get too excited and make an exasperated exclamation of thanks, as this can be off-putting. You want to convey that you are OK with, and accepting of, the compliment, and that you appreciate it and weren't desperate to hear it.
>
> Add something to the compliment that pertains to it. For example, if someone compliments your jewelry, you can say, “Thanks, I got it at this great store, I love it.” If someone compliments something you did, you could say, “Thanks, I worked really hard.” This is just something to show that you agree with the compliment or that you at least appreciate what the person said.

(From [*eHow*](http://www.ehow.com/), ["How to Answer Compliments"](http://www.ehow.com/how_8391166_answer-compliments.html), Amy Davidson.)

Another,

> **Responding to compliments:**
>   For example, "That's a beautiful dress!" Respond. "Thank you very much!", "I'm so glad you like it."
>
> Don't belittle and say, "Oh this is an inexpensive dress", "Oh an old dress", "Or really? I don't think it really fits me".

(From [*Elegant Woman*](http://www.elegantwoman.org/emily-post-etiquette.html), ["Emily Post Etiquette on the Art of Conversation"](http://www.elegantwoman.org/emily-post-etiquette.html).)

Comment: You don't need to be boring. I know you can be witty and elegant. What's the point of being boring, then? Sheesh.

Answer (score 3):

How about:

1- Its your beautiful eyes that grant those flowers their beauty.

2- These flowers cannot compete with the beauty of your eyes.